# Trying to change colors, but not sure how to change div element from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

New to JavaScript and CSS and I am trying to give the user a button that will change the background color of a game board (set up with div) randomly when pressed.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.conway {
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: courier;
        float: left;
        width: 800px;
        height: 488px;
        background-color: green;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: gold;
    }
</style>
```

and inside my script tag I have the following:

```
     function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }

    my.changeBackgroundColor = function () {
        document.getElementById(conway).style.background-color = getRandomColor();                
    }
```

But the DOM is not letting me assign the new color.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your HTML where the div is defined with the ID="conway"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-color` should be `backgroundColor`:

```
document.getElementById(conway).style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
```

or this is allowed as well:

```
document.getElementById(conway).style["background-color"] = getRandomColor();
```

In JavaScript, you can refer to an object property using dotted notation and a property name *literal* (`obj.foo`), or using bracketed notation and a property name *string* (`obj["foo"]`). A property name *literal* has to be a valid JavaScript identifier, and obviously you can't have a `-` in an identifier, it looks like a minus sign. So instead, camelCase is used where hyphens would normally be in the style object.

---

Side note: You haven't shown your HTML, or the content of your `conway` variable, but I assume you have an `id` on the element in question, and that the `conway` variable contains that `id`. E.g.:

```
<div id="cell23">...</div>
```

and

```
conway = "cell23"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `backgroundColor` instead off of `style`.

JS is treating `-` as the minus operator.

Comment: to expand on this, javascript does not allow `-` in variable names. that's why it treats it as the subtraction operator. css and html attributes that contain dashes must be converted to mixedCase when you access them in JS.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to access the DOM element by ID using `document.getElementById(conway)` but `conway` is a **class**. So you either have to give the targeted div an ID or use `document.getElementsByClassName('conway');` which will effectively get all of the element that have a class name `conway`. Not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the wrong property. It should be:

```
my.changeBackgroundColor = function() {
      document.getElementById(conway).style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working **[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s4Kds/)**

You had few problems within your code,

Line:

```
document.getElementById(conway).style.background-color = getRandomColor();
```

Should be defined as: (see how backgroundColor is written and usage of "" for id).

```
document.getElementById("conway").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
```

Also, remember to apply your styles to id element (can't see whether your div has a class conway defined or not.)

```
div#conway { .. }
```

After that it works great.

I also recommend that you check **[CSS properties reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference)** which lists formats used for giving css attributes using javascript. In other words, the problem which you had.!

Cheers.